# Calculation of average cost

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
Transaction_Date    Ticker  Cost    Shares  Trade_Cost  Ave_Cost    Total_Shares    Total_Cost
12/1/2014    AAA    1.50    1,000   1,500.00    1.50    1,000   1,500.00 
12/1/2014   BBB 10.00   250     2,500.00    10.00   250     2,500.00 
12/10/2014  BBB 11.25   200     2,250.00    10.56   450     4,750.00 
12/12/2014  AAA 1.75    800     1,400.00    1.61    1,800   2,900.00 
12/15/2014  CCC 32.00   100     3,200.00    1.00    3,200   3,200.00
```

I have to calculate the Ave Cost, Total Shares, and Total Cost.

My formula for Total Shares for the second entry of BBB is

```
=SUMIF(B2:B4,B2,D2:D4)
```

while the formula for Total Cost is

```
=SUMIF(B2:B4,B2,E2:E4)
```

Next, for the second entry of AAA on the date 12/12/2014,

```
Total Shares = SUMIF(B2:B5,B5,D2:D5)

Total Cost =  SUMIF(B2:B5,B5,E2:E5)
```

Dragging this formula down would require me to manually change the range in the SUMIF formula. How do I calculate the running Total Shares and Total Cost at every entry date without manually changing the range in the SUMIF formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your data start from cell `A1` and the first row has the column names.

In cell `I2` put the function and copy down `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:B2=B2),$D$1:D2)`
This is for the `Running Total Shares`.

You work the same way for the other running totals. For the Running average totals put this formula in cell `I2`: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:B2=B2),$D$1:D2)/SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:B2=B2))` and copy down.

With the `sumif` you could do the following:
`=SUMIF($B$1:B2,B2,$D$1:D2)` and copy down.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Running Average Cost should be weighted. So the denominator should be SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:B2=B2),$D$1:D2).